Flutter Firebase User Document ID & UID is Different
I have a collection "user" and the document ID of the user is different from the current user's UID. So when I use FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid in the following code it doesn't work. I am using anonymous login to create users not sure if this makes a difference.
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).collection('subcollection')

Document ID

UID

Would really appreciate it, if someone could clarify:

If this is normal Firebase behavior make docid and uid different.
How to access current user's data in this scenario.
How to make both the document ID and uid the same.


You can make the document ID whatever string you want, as long as it's valid.  If it conveniences you to make the document ID the same as the user ID, then do that.  It's up to you - there are no rules that we can tell you that you must follow.  It sounds like you chose not to make them the same coming into this question, so maybe you should revisit that decision.

Can you please explain the process to give doc id and uid the same name, because the document in user is created automatically not sure how to achieve this.

You can give the document ID any string you want.  See the documentation for an example.

The doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) in your code creates a reference to a document with the same ID as the UID of the current user. If this ends up referring to a document that you don't expect, that is most likely because the code runs when the currentUser is not yet set to be for the user that you expected.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the suggestion. The problem I'm facing is that the current user's doc id is not the same as UID, if it was then I could access the current user with the FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid. Trying to figure out how to have anonymous login and create the user doc with the same name as UID.

Hey Raj.  Thanks for clarifying, but I understood that already. That's why I said that your code does precisely what you seem to want, so it's more likely that currentUser does not have the value you expect when it runs. I recommend setting a breakpoint on this line, and then running it in a debugger to verify that.\

The FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid returns:

The user's unique ID.

And to answer your questions.

If this is normal Firebase behavior to make docid and uid different.

No, it's not. If you write a document to Firestore when the authentication is successful using the following document reference:
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)

You'll end up having a document in Firestore that has the same document ID as the UID that comes from the authentication process.

How do I access the current user's data in this scenario?

Exactly as already do, using FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.

How do we make both the document ID and UID the same?

Using the above document reference and calling the DocumentReference#set() function, but only when the authentication is successful. Please also notice, that if you sign the user out and sign in anonymously again, a new UID is generated. There is no way you can use an old anonymous UID.

Hey Raj. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Hi Alex, really appreciate you took time to answer the question and your solution is right but I had already posted the answer to my own question, I found part of the solution in Firebase documentation and the other part of it in another Stackoverflow question.

This seems to be a bug from FirebaseAuthentication. I have been encountering this at random times within the day since October. Very hard to replicate but it happens. the user gets a different UID when authenticated.

The following code creates the user document with UID as it's name.
try {
// Logs in the user anonymously
final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();

// Gets the UID
String uid = userCredential.user!.uid;

// Creates a field inside the user document to store the UID
final userData = {"UID": uid, };

// Creates the user document with the UID as it's name
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(uid).set(userData);

print("Signed in with temporary account.");
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        print("Anonymous auth hasn't been enabled for this project.");
        break;
      default:
        print("Unknown error.");
    }
  }

